# td onclick not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am working in MVC4 and using tables, When I set onclick on `<td>` element of table then related function is not working.

This is how I am doing-

```
 <tr>

      <td style="cursor:pointer" onclick="D();">
       #= DisplayName #</td>
      </tr>
```

**jQuery function-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function D() {
                    $('td').click(function (event) { loadPartially(event, '@Url.Contact_PartialView_Main()?ContactID=@Model.ContactID') });
                    alert("aa");
                });
            </script>
```

When this didn't work I tried giving it an ID-

```
 <tr>

          <td style="cursor:pointer" id="Open">
           #= DisplayName #</td>
          </tr>
```

**jQuery function for this-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                    $(document).ready(function {
                        $('#Open').click(function (event) { loadPartially(event, '@Url.Contact_PartialView_Main()?ContactID=@Model.ContactID') });
                        alert("aa");
                    });
                </script>
```

I am trying to get load partial event on click of this  element of table.

But somehow it is not working. I am not sure if i can use onclick function on `<td>` element of table.

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting the `alert` to happen? What does `loadPartially` do? Did you try putting an `alert` as the first thing in the `click` handler to see if that executes? You can definitely handle the `click` event of a `<td>` element.

Comment: @lan: I have updated tags, yes alert is not coming . loadPartially calling a new page `onclick`

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
$(document).ready(function {
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are mixing an old school approach with a jquery one (admittidly, you are also mixing in syntax that simply won't work).

Here is how you would accomplish binding an onclick event absent jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function D() {
       alert('omg!');
    }
</script>

...

<td onclick="D()">
</td>
```

Now if you want to use the jquery approach it would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#IdSelector').click(function() {
        alert('omg!');
    });
</script>

...

<td id="IdSelector">
</td>
```

With the jquery approach, you sacrifice an easy ability to immediately identify what will happen during the td's onclick for separation of concerns between the javascript logic and the presentation layer (html)

I prefer the jQuery approach as it doesn't have to be concerned with a few annoying syntactical issues you have to watch out for when performing inline javascript as well as being much more readable IMO.

**EDIT:**

Demo for jquery approach - http://jsfiddle.net/jSnAh/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){//You have missed paranthesis of function()
     $('#Open').live('click',function(event) { 
             alert("aa");
             loadPartially(event, '@Url.Contact_PartialView_Main()?ContactID=@Model.ContactID');
      });  
  });
```

Comment: The thing is it's not calling an alert here.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` on a `<td>` is valid.

Put your `alert` as the first line of the function `D()` to ensure it is being called correctly.

Using FireFox, install the Web Developer toolbar and Firebug plugins. Press F12, click the console tab, then click the `<td>`. If there are any errors, you'll see them in the console tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
Firstly give a id or class to your td


<tr>

  <td style="cursor:pointer" id='PerformAction'>
   #= DisplayName #</td>
  </tr>


$(document).ready(function (){
$('#PerformAction').click(function (event) { 
    loadPartially(event, '@Url.Contact_PartialView_Main()?ContactID=@Model.ContactID')
    alert("aa");
});
});
```